# Discord.JS Command Handler not working or updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to add a command handler to my bot, however, only one command is working and no matter how I change the command, it does not update. Here is my code.

This is at the top underneath the packages and above the on ready code.

```
fs.readdir('./commands/', (_err, files) => {
 files.forEach((file) => {
  if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return;
   bot.commands = new Discord.Collection()
  let command = require(`./commands/${file}`); // access all details though this variable
  bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
  console.log(` Command loaded: ${command.name}`);
 });
});
```

This is in the resources command

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")

module.exports = {
 name: 'resources',
 // any other details you might like, such as:
 description: 'Shows resources',
 execute(bot, message, args, prefix) {
  // the actual function
    let resourceText = fs.readFileSync('txtfiles/resources.txt', 'utf8')
    message.suppressEmbeds(true)
    message.channel.send(resourceText)
    
 }
 }
```

The resources command works just fine, but the ship command does not.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fs = require("fs")

module.exports = {
 name: 'ship',
 // any other details you might like, such as:
 description: 'ships people',
 execute(bot, message, args, prefix) {
  // the actual function
    message.channel.send("please work")
    
 }
 }
```

And this is in the "on messageCreate" thing

```
if(cmd===`${prefix}resources`){bot.commands.get('resources').execute(bot, message, args, prefix);}

if(cmd===`${prefix}ship`){bot.commands.get('ship').execute(bot, message, args, prefix);}
```

I have tried putting these underneath the packages

```
delete require.cache['./index.js'];
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./index.js')]
```

However, I am getting this error message
`Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')`

The resources command works just fine, even if we delete all the code in the file, and the ship command does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rather than put an `if (cmd ===` block for every command, try using a dynamic one that won't require you to update your `messageCreate` section, every time you add a new command or delete one.

messageCreate section:

```js
bot.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    const cmd = bot.commands.get(command)

    if (!cmd) {
        console.log("Unknown command")
        return
    } else {
        cmd.run(bot, message, args)
    }
})
```

Then you'll have to update your existing command that does work to match this style but just make any new ones like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'Command Name',
    description: 'Command description',
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        // the actual function
    }
}
```

So your `ships` command would look like this

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ships',
    description: 'ships people',
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        message.channel.send({
            content: 'Please work'
        })
    }
}
```

I'd change your command collection to this

```js
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection()
const commandList = []

const commands = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for (const file of commands) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
    commandList.push(`${file.split('.'[0])}`)
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command)
}
 console.log(` Commands loaded: ${commandList}`)
```

Comment: Updated to consolidate

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I am still getting an error. When I do either of the commands, whether it be resources or ship, I get the following error. `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get'`)

Comment: Update: I am no longer getting that error after changing client to bot, but it is now not recognizing any commands. Also, on every message, it is responding with the code I put for responding with unknown command.

Comment: I have updated my answer to change the command collection let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I got a new error. The error I got was `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined` This happens when the bot is ran.

Comment: That was my bad. Please replace the `const commands = fs.readdir` with `const commands = fs.readdirSync`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243173/discussion-between-kaspr-and-starryava).